# providing source for an Image control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to databind into a element inside my custom class. i've given the ItemSource as the ObservableCollection of telerik:RadTransitionControl via an attached property. However, I need to provide the image member as the source to Image control. I tried the following method and was unsuccessful.

```
<Grid Background="Black">
        <telerik:RadTransitionControl   x:Name="radControl" adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.ItemChangeDelay="0:0:3" 
                                      adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.CurrentSelectedIndex="0"
                                      adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.IndexChanged="{Binding TopItemCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                      adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ImagePaths}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="650">
            <telerik:RadTransitionControl.Transition>
                <telerik:MotionBlurredZoomTransition />
            </telerik:RadTransitionControl.Transition>

            <telerik:RadTransitionControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePaths.AdImage}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadTransitionControl.ContentTemplate>

        </telerik:RadTransitionControl>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: what were the binding errors? you should see them in the output window.

Comment: nothing. the screen just left blank without displaying an image.

Comment: I mean the visual studio output window (View -> Output). When you have issues related to binding, you should always check there. It may save you a trip here. ;)

Answer (score 1):

an `ImagePaths` object is already set as the DataContext for the item. this means that the binding is already pointing (so to speak) at an instance of the object. so, when you tell it to bind on `ImagePaths.AdImage` it does not know how to find the property you are looking for. Good news is, all you have to do is provide the path on the object-- remove the `ImagePaths` part (and the dot) and you should be good to go.

for example...

```
class something 
{
  public string someImage {...}
}

<DataTemplate> <!--------- the data context of this item is an instance of
                           my "something" class, so i need to set the path
                           to be the property on the object --->

   <Image Source="{Binding Path=someImage}" />

</DataTemplate>
```

[here is a very helpful article on debugging bindings in WPF](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52)
for more info [here is an excellent article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx)
[here is a datatemplate article from Dr. WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/data-templates/)

Comment: Replaced with the following statements without success    <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=AdImage}" />
                </DataTemplate>

Comment: you should take a look at the debugging bindings article... http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52  it will show you how to add debugging messages for your bindings